# Exception while using Play WS to access a REST WebService

Tags: scala, web-services, rest, playframework-2.5

I want to use the Play WS Standalone (outside a Play Project) to call a simple Hello World RESTfull Web Service.

I'm Using an SBT Poject in Intelij IDEA whith this configuration :

```
name := "ScalaSbtProject"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
libraryDependencies +=  "com.typesafe.play" % "play-ws_2.11" % "2.5.10"
```

Here's my code :

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSClient
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits._
    implicit val actor = ActorSystem()
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    val wsClient = AhcWSClient()
    val response = wsClient
      .url("http://localhost:8080/WebService_war_exploded/service/test")
      .get()
    response.onComplete {
      case Success(re) => { println(re.body)}
      case Failure(e) => { e.getStackTrace.foreach(println)}
      }
    wsClient.close()
    }
}
```

which throws this Exception :

```
Response Is Failed :
http://localhost:8080
org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener.onFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:160)
org.asynchttpclient.netty.request.NettyChannelConnector$1.onFailure(NettyChannelConnector.java:103)
org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:28)
org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20)
io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:514)
io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:486)
io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:427)
io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:129)
io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel.doClose(AbstractNioChannel.java:458)
io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doClose(NioSocketChannel.java:235)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.doClose0(AbstractChannel.java:632)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.close(AbstractChannel.java:611)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.close(AbstractChannel.java:554)
io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.closeAll(NioEventLoop.java:637)
io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:406)
io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you hit your localhost service url via curl? Is it HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: Sorry for being late, I dont understand your question but i'm actionally solved my problem by changing the API @Barry